# I can't seem to be able to execute more than 20 scripts simultaneously called from a single IP ( apache )

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have a system of 50 php scripts that all do the same thing. I run them in parallel to gain processing speed ( they feed some data and store it in database ).

When I run call them via the browser from a localhost, I can't seem to get more than 10-20 working before the response in the browser slows down ( I can't access phpmyadmin that quick or any other scripts etc. )

But when I access the same server from other machine ( with different IP ) - all runs smoothly - PHPmyadmin, other scripts on the same machine.

Obviously something must be limiting the amount of scripts processed per IP ( even if it's localhost ) Because I can get more of them running if I call them from other IP.

How do I know what is the problem caused by and how to overcome this?

I've increased the parameters (MaxConnections, ServerLimit etc.) in the config files but that didn't seem to do anything.

Also - I've read something about MPM and workers but I don't understand - if I don't use the MPM - does that mean my scripts are being run sequentially? How do I know I am running it?

I want to achieve maximum parallelism with my Apache server. Those 50 scripts all pull data from outside source but I can't run them all from one machine because after 20 of them are being run, the machine stops sending requests as quickly to the browser.

Best regards

Comment: Why are you using the browser? Did you know that you can execute PHP from SSH (Terminal) from within the server to avoid apache and it's limitations.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? I think my browser settings may also limit me. Also, I am running a Windows Server 2008 OS.

Comment: Are you on shared hosting or do you have your own server? If you are on shared hosting, you may need to request SSH access. Once connected (with something like putty), just run `php file.php` as many times as you want

Comment: I have my own dedicated machine. Is there any parameter I can add to php.exe to make it run any given script in a loop? So it calls it once again when it finished processing the last time?

Comment: Great, so you just need to login and run (from any directory) `/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php` which will execute the file. Repeat as you please.

Comment: There isn't a native PHP command, but you can write a simple bash script to do it, or create a cronjob (search for cron or crontab)